# Android application is crashed, when build from my machine, but not from other machine

Tags: android

I'm using a mac machine to build a android application, but it will crashed when run on device. but with the same code and key I build the application using another machine (windows). it is working well on devices.

Using my mac I already build several other apps and those are working well.

Can any one give me a solution?

Comment: whats showing up on `LogCat` ?

Comment: app is working well with my phone also, But my client try to install that on his phone and it crashed. He don't know how to take the log from phone.

Comment: get the clients device specifications,screenshots and try to reproduce on emulator.Exactly what caused the error may want you to ask him what steps to follow etc

Comment: thanks for the help. this app is strongly using location data. is it possible to test this app on emulator with out any code changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the feedback of your client device as Kumar suggested.

get the clients device specifications,screenshots and try to reproduce on emulator.Exactly what caused the error may want you to ask him what steps to follow to reproduce the error.etc

> is it possible to test this app on emulator with out any code changes?

Yes.You have a DDMS perspective.Just go to the top right corner above the coding window.There's a sort of plus (+) button there.From there you have a DDMS perspective.In this perspective,you can control emulator.You can feed the GPS co-ordinates here.

Look at this

[image: GPS Control]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using some new API that your client doesn't have. He might be running an older OS. Run Android Lint checks and see if you get an API warnings.

Check your client's OS version and your own. Create emulator with your client's OS version and see if it's crashing.

Comment: thanks for the help. this app is strongly using location data. is it possible to test this app on emulator with out any code changes?

Comment: Should be. There's an Emulator control view in eclipse, which you can use to push location co-ordinates to your emulator